# Fire a method after selection in a spinner

Tags: android, listview, spinner

First of all Happy New Year to everyone!! Second I would like to know if somenone can help me with this problem. I have a ListActivity in which every row has a spinner to select a batch number.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.picking.utils.RelativeLayout
android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutPickingRow"                                                                      
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="70dp"                                  
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutPickingRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    >

 //TextViews and other things

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerLote"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:visibility="visible"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

what I want to achive is to "simulate" the onListItemClick method when a bacthnumber is selected

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, int position, long id)
```

I have a custom spinner adapter and a custom adapter too for the list with a holder pattern

```
package com.picking.adapters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import  com.picking.POJOS.LotesAbiertos;
import  com.pickingR;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SpinnerCustomAdapter<L> extends ArrayAdapter<LotesAbiertos> {
    private ArrayList<LotesAbiertos> list;
    private Activity context;
    Resources resources;
    public SpinnerCustomAdapter(Activity activity, int resource, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<LotesAbiertos> list) {
        super(activity, resource, textViewResourceId, list);
        this.list = list;
        this.context = activity;
        resources = activity.getResources();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, parent, false);
        LotesAbiertos item = list.get(position);
        TextView tvLote = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        if (item != null) {   // Parse the data from each object and set it.
            if (item.status.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                tvLote.setText("SIN LOTES");
            } else {
                tvLote.setText(item.loteFormateado);
            }
        }
        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   // This view starts when we click the spinner.
        final int positionRow = position;
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_drop, parent, false);
        }
        TextView tvLote = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        TextView tvAcceso = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        LotesAbiertos item = list.get(position);
        if (item != null) {   // Parse the data from each object and set it.
            if (position == 0) {
                tvLote.setText("Lotes");
                row.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.green_ligth));
            } else {
                if (item.status.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                    tvLote.setText("SIN LOTES");
                } else {
                    tvLote.setText(item.loteFormateado.substring(0, 5));
                    Spannable secondWord = new SpannableString(item.loteFormateado.substring(item.loteFormateado.length() - 3));
                    secondWord.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, secondWord.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    tvLote.append(secondWord);
                }
                row.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white));
            }
            if (item.status.equalsIgnoreCase("0") || item.status.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                tvLote.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.green_dark));
                tvAcceso.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                tvLote.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.dark_grey));
                tvAcceso.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        return row;
    }
}
```

Considering I have the adapters and the activity in different packages I can`t call the method as it is protected, but I can have a method like this.

```
public void fireOnListItemClick(View view, int position, long id) {
    onListItemClick(getListView(), view, position, id);
}
```

I can call this method from the spinnner adapter but the question is how I get the

```
view, position, id
```

parameters of the row of the listview to pass them to the method? Shoud I have in the spinner adapter a setOnClickListener like this?

```
 @Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   

    /*..........*/

    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            /*Call fireOnListItemClick*/
        }
    });
    return row;
}
```

Thanks in advance for you time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [OnItemSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html)

[Example usage](https://android--code.blogspot.co.nz/2015/08/android-spinner-onitemselected.html)

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            tv.setText("Spinner selected : ");
            tv.setText(tv.getText() + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            //Another interface callback
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll give it a try.